# What is the time complexity of the following nested loops in Big-Theta notation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops, big-o

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < n; j *= 2)
        for (int k = j; k < n; k *= 2);
```

I know the time complexity is **O(n.log<sup>2</sup>(n))**, but I want it in Big-Theta notation and would like to know how to prove this is indeed the time complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Big Theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) is the notation for when the time complexity is the same in the worst and best case.

As this is the situation you have at hand, you can just write what you have in big O in Big Theta.

You would have a difference in worst/best case when there is other, unknown data involved, like an array of size , but with values in it that you do not know before hand. In that case an algorithm may have a different running time depending on that data. Another example is when you have some random generator involved (which is just another way to get unknown data).

But as you don't have any unknown data in your algorithm, the time complexity can be written with Big Theta notation.

#### Proof of the time complexity

The complexity however is not Θ(log²). It is in fact a plain Θ().

The time complexity can be derived from the number of increments made to the `count` variable in this extended code, because for every iteration of the outer loop, the middle one is expected at least once, and for every iteration of the middle one, the innermost loop is also executed at least once:

```js
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < n; j *= 2)
        for (k = j; k < n; k *= 2)
            count++;
```

The inner two loops make the same number of increments as in this alternative (pseudo) code, where *log* stands for the logarithm with base 2:

```js
for (j = log(i); j < log(n); j++)
    for (k = j; k < log(n); k++)
        count++;
```

Or also:

```js
for (j = 0; j < log(n) - log(i); j++)
    for (k = j; k < log(n) - log(i); k++)
        count++;
```

Define  as the number of iterations made by the loop on  for a given , then  is log−log rounded upward to the closest integer. The number of increments made for a given  corresponds to the number of ways to pick 2 values among  values, where the second is greater or equal to the first. This number is (+1)/2.

Removing the upward rounding, we can find an upper bound for , by adding one to log−log. Let's redefine  as this upper bound:

= log − log + 1

Then we get this upper bound for the number of `count` increases made by the inner two loops for a given :

½(+1)

Breaking this down into the logarithm components, we get:

½(log − log + 1)(log − log + 2)
     = ½log² + (3/2)log + 1 + (−log−3/2)log + ½log²

Adding to this the effect of the outer loop, we get this upper bound for the overall `count`:

count < ½log² + (3/2)log +  + (−log−3/2)Σlog + ½Σ<sub><sub>i</sub></sub>log²

The sums over  need to be resolved. The sum of logarithms is the logarithm of the product, so we have this equality:

Σlog = log(!)

The  comes from the number of iterations of the outer loop. In fact, the outer loop does not iterate that many times, because its last iteration is with  = n−1, but for the purpose of defining an upper bound, we can choose to take  on board as well.

By [applying the Stirling formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/385599/341715) with conversion of some natural logarithms (noted here as **ln**) to 2-based logarithms, we get this useful asymptotical approximation:

log(!) = (+½)log − /ln2 + ½log(2π) + O(1/)
     = log + (−1/ln2) + ½log + ½log(2π) + O(1/)

For the last term with a sum, Σlog², we can use the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums), and with the [integral over this function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(log(x)%5E2)) (see also ["sum of log squared terms"](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/sum-of-log-squared-terms.627139/)), we derive:

Σlog² = [log² − (2/ln2)log + 2/ln²2] − 2/ln²2 + ½log² + O(log/)
     = log² − (2/ln2)log + (2/ln²2) + (−2)/ln²2 + ½log² + O(log/)

Taking this into what we had for `count`:

count < ½log² + (3/2)log + 
     + (−log−3/2)Σlog
     + ½Σlog²

We get:

count < ½log² + (3/2)log + 
     + (−log−3/2)[ log + (−1/ln2) + ½log + ½log(2π) ]
     + ½[ log² − (2/ln2)log + (2/ln²2) + (−2)/ln²2 + ½log²]
     + O(log/)

= ½log² + (3/2)log + 
     + (−−½)⋅log + (1/ln2)log + (−½)log(2π)log + (−3/2−3/4)log + (3/(2ln2)) + (−3/4)log(2π)
     + ½log² − (1/ln2)log + (1/ln²2) + (−1)/ln²2 + (1/4)log²
     + O(log/)

Bringing all terms together that have the same significance in terms of , it turns out that the terms with factor log² and log eliminate each other. And so we get:

count < (1 + 3/(2ln2) + 1/ln²2)
     + (−1/4)log² + ((−1/2)log(2π)−3/4)log
     + (−3/4)log(2π) + (−1)/(ln²2)
     + O(log/)

So this is ... Θ(), and as (1 + 3/(2ln2) + 1/ln²2) is about 5.24 and the few next expressions have negative coefficients, the following upper bound exists for `count`:

count < 6

This is an upper limit. It cannot be better than Θ() since the outer loop is executed Θ() times.

#### Testing it

Empirically you can see that the expression `count/n` for large  converges towards the value 4. Here is a little snippet that keeps increment , performs the algorithm and outputs this fraction:

```js
function f(n) {
    var i, j, k, count = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = i; j < n; j *= 2)
            for (k = j; k < n; k *= 2)
                count++;
    }
    return count;
}

// keep increasing n forever, and print f(n)/n
var n = 2;
setInterval(function () {
    document.body.textContent = 'n = ' + n 
                              + '\nf(n) = ' + f(n)
                              + '\nf(n)/n = ' + (f(n)/n);
    n = n + 1;
}, 1);
```

```css
body { white-space: pre }
```

NB: I have the feeling that there must be a more concise and elegant proof for this, but this is what I could come up with for now.

Comment: shouldn't this be `Theta(n * log(n) * log(log(n)))` ?

Comment: @trincot I know my code runs the same in best and worst case. But why it's theta(n.log(n)). I need a proof.

Comment: @trincot Why shouldn't this be `Theta(n * log(n) * log(log(n)))` or even `Theta(n * log(n))`?

Comment: Your statement was *"I know time complexity is O(n.log2(n))"*, so are you now saying that you don't know? Because if it is known that that is true, then it follows that the Big Theta is like that. Your question was about notation: *"...but I want it in Big-Theta notation."*. Now I get the impression your question is different.